# open pdf in new tab DOMPDF

Tags: php, laravel

After form submission, I am trying to open the pdf generated in a new tab. This is my code:

```
 public function invoice(Request $request) {
        $invoice = $this->invoice_form($request);

        $filename = 'pdfs/nir'.$invoice->invoice_id.'.pdf';

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf-generation.invoice', compact('invoice'));

        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

        file_put_contents(''.$filename, $pdf->output());
        return $pdf->stream($filename, array("Attachment" => false));
    }
```

It works fine, but unfortunately it opens in the same tab. I want the pdf to open in a new tab. By the way, I also added target="_blank" in the form

Comment: You will need to use javascript to open a new tab. Any response from the server side will not let you open a new tab

Comment: I understand. Any guidance to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this. In my invoice() function I used Session:

```
Session::flash('fileToDownload', url($filename));
```

And then, in my header.blade.php I placed this:

```
@if(Session::has('fileToDownload'))
    <script>
        window.open("{{ Session::get('fileToDownload') }}", '_blank').focus();
    </script>
@endif
```

Hope it is going to help you!